# Scipy Sparse - distance matrix (Scikit or Scipy)

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, scikit-learn, sparse-matrix

I am trying to compute nearest neighbour clustering on a Scipy sparse matrix returned from scikit-learn's `DictVectorizer`. However, when I try to compute the distance matrix with scikit-learn I get an error message using 'euclidean' distance through both `pairwise.euclidean_distances` and `pairwise.pairwise_distances`. I was under the impression that scikit-learn could calculate these distance matrices.

My matrix is highly sparse with a shape of: `<364402x223209 sparse matrix of type <class 'numpy.float64'>
    with 728804 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>`.

I have also tried methods such as `pdist` and `kdtree` in Scipy but have received other errors of not being able to process the result.

Can anyone please point me to a solution that would effectively allow me calculate the distance matrix and/or the nearest neighbour result?

Some example code:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.feature_extraction import DictVectorizer
from sklearn.neighbors import NearestNeighbors
from sklearn.metrics import pairwise
import scipy.spatial

file = 'FileLocation'
data = []
FILE = open(file,'r')
for line in FILE:
    templine = line.strip().split(',')
    data.append({'user':str(int(templine[0])),str(int(templine[1])):int(templine[2])})
FILE.close()

vec = DictVectorizer()
X = vec.fit_transform(data)

result = scipy.spatial.KDTree(X)
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.2/lib/python3.2/site-packages/scipy/spatial/kdtree.py", line 227, in __init__
    self.n, self.m = np.shape(self.data)
ValueError: need more than 0 values to unpack
```

Similarly, if I run:

```
scipy.spatial.distance.pdist(X,'euclidean')
```

I get the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.2/lib/python3.2/site-packages/scipy/spatial/distance.py", line 1169, in pdist
    [X] = _copy_arrays_if_base_present([_convert_to_double(X)])
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.2/lib/python3.2/site-packages/scipy/spatial/distance.py", line 113, in _convert_to_double
    X = X.astype(np.double)
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

Finally, running `NearestNeighbor` in scikit-learn results in a memory error using:

```
nbrs = NearestNeighbors(n_neighbors=10, algorithm='brute')
```

Comment: What kind of errors do you get? What code are you running?

Comment: Please edit that information into your question: a minimal example that that shows what you're doing, and the actual errors that you get.

Comment: Thanks! Now this looks much better.

Comment: You want to compute the distance between all rows of `X`? So a size `364402x364402` array?

Comment: Yes and no. Since it is a sparse matrix, I would expect there to be solutions to intelligently calculate the distances and store the result in a similarly sparse matrix. In a similar fashion as Mahout does.

Answer (score 4):

First, you can't use `KDTree` and `pdist` with sparse matrix, you have to convert it to dense (your choice whether it's your option):

```
>>> X
<2x3 sparse matrix of type '<type 'numpy.float64'>'
        with 4 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>

>>> scipy.spatial.KDTree(X.todense())
<scipy.spatial.kdtree.KDTree object at 0x34d1e10>
>>> scipy.spatial.distance.pdist(X.todense(),'euclidean')
array([ 6.55743852])
```

Second, from [the docs](http://scikit-learn.org/0.12/modules/neighbors.html):

> Efficient brute-force neighbors searches can be very competitive for small data samples. However, as the number of samples N grows, the brute-force approach quickly becomes infeasible.

You might want to try 'ball_tree' algorithm and see if it can handle your data.

Comment: I originally tried the ball tree but it gave a warning that it had to revert to the brute force algorithm. Do you know of any Python based methods that can actually calculate the sparse distance matrix on a matrix of these dimensions?

Comment: @user2694306 Your **euclidean** distance matrix must be dense (possibly without any zero value, I guess), so it has to span more than 74 Gb of memory. I doubt it is possible at all.

Answer (score 3):

From your comment:

> Since it is a sparse matrix, I would expect there to be solutions to intelligently calculate the distances and store the result in a similarly sparse matrix.

Basic math shows that this is only possible in the case that your input matrix contains a massive number of duplicates, because Euclidean distance is only zero for two exactly equal points (this is actually one of the [axioms of distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_%28mathematics%29#Definition)). So if you remove duplicates this might work.

Otherwise, depending on your problem, you might be able to use `sklearn.metrics.pairwise_distances_argmin_min` or cosine similarity, `X * X.T`, which has the reverse ordering compared to Euclidean distance.